# Quickest way of determining if a point lies within a sf object

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf

I am trying to determine which entries of a dataframe of geographical points (crs = 28992) lay within a list of polygons (class: SpatialPoints), i.e. for each polygon I want to obtain a list containing all the points from the dataframe that are located within the specified polygon. Below are the first two polygons from the polygon list I want to use.

```
> dput(Severity_matrix[1:2,17])

list(new("SpatialPoints", coords = structure(c(365901.718425453, 
365840.735248348, 365658.787059115, 365358.861441992, 364945.883167318, 
364426.633326947, 363809.637988903, 363105.028199579, 362324.373632234, 
361480.492613283, 360587.241645727, 359659.287885757, 358711.868308457, 
357760.539517095, 356820.922304122, 355908.4451582, 355038.090928836, 
354224.150808417, 353479.989671215, 352817.82662253, 352248.534361316, 
351781.460650762, 351424.274828283, 351182.841875208, 351061.126113954, 
351061.126113954, 351182.841875208, 351424.274828283, 351781.460650762, 
352248.534361316, 352817.82662253, 353479.989671215, 354224.150808417, 
355038.090928836, 355908.4451582, 356820.922304122, 357760.539517094, 
358711.868308457, 359659.287885757, 360587.241645727, 361480.492613283, 
362324.373632234, 363105.028199579, 363809.637988903, 364426.633326947, 
364945.883167318, 365358.861441992, 365658.787059115, 365840.735248348, 
365901.718425453, 365901.718425453, 471406.967507941, 470123.485439601, 
468861.07811134, 467640.474216585, 466481.716037545, 465403.830351483, 
464424.516011563, 463559.853332175, 462824.040050607, 462229.1582006, 
461784.975725686, 461498.786089822, 461375.288518918, 461416.510839672, 
461621.776182718, 461987.714096798, 462508.31589148, 463175.033299687, 
463976.91884001, 464900.805574046, 465931.523307164, 467052.147682681, 
468244.278079334, 469488.339748967, 470763.90523336, 472050.029782522, 
473325.595266915, 474569.656936548, 475761.787333201, 476882.411708718, 
477913.129441836, 478837.016175871, 479638.901716194, 480305.619124402, 
480826.220919084, 481192.158833164, 481397.42417621, 481438.646496964, 
481315.14892606, 481028.959290196, 480584.776815282, 479989.894965275, 
479254.081683707, 478389.419004318, 477410.104664399, 476332.218978337, 
475173.460799296, 473952.856904542, 472690.449576281, 471406.967507941, 
471406.967507941), .Dim = c(51L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
    c("X_rotated", "Y_rotated"))), bbox = structure(c(351061.126113954, 
461375.288518918, 365901.718425453, 481438.646496964), .Dim = c(2L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(c("X_rotated", "Y_rotated"), c("min", "max"
))), proj4string = new("CRS", projargs = "+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.1561605555556 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs")), 
    new("SpatialPoints", coords = structure(c(240120.939367694, 
    240112.69975411, 240088.116207587, 240047.592389278, 239991.79369916, 
    239921.636350181, 239838.272324073, 239743.07045584, 239637.593957525, 
    239523.574750316, 239402.885026441, 239277.506507832, 239149.497906296, 
    239020.961119532, 238894.006718026, 238770.719289539, 238653.12321024, 
    238543.1494045, 238442.603639167, 238353.13687293, 238276.218147616, 
    238213.110466569, 238164.850056166, 238132.229351013, 238115.783982185, 
    238115.783982185, 238132.229351013, 238164.850056166, 238213.110466569, 
    238276.218147616, 238353.13687293, 238442.603639167, 238543.1494045, 
    238653.12321024, 238770.719289539, 238894.006718026, 239020.961119532, 
    239149.497906296, 239277.506507832, 239402.885026441, 239523.574750316, 
    239637.593957525, 239743.07045584, 239838.272324073, 239921.636350181, 
    239991.79369916, 240047.592389278, 240088.116207587, 240112.69975411, 
    240120.939367694, 240120.939367694, 396371.528948936, 394860.461431681, 
    393374.205601284, 391937.16573739, 390572.937994835, 389303.922955435, 
    388150.957811054, 387132.974217487, 386266.687437198, 385566.321875167, 
    385043.377514561, 384706.441087325, 384561.045080277, 384609.576891834, 
    384851.239630992, 385282.065202255, 385894.979461654, 386679.918373994, 
    387623.993264036, 388711.702448185, 389925.185771709, 391244.517871984, 
    392648.035352399, 394112.692494728, 395614.439669186, 397128.618228686, 
    398630.365403144, 400095.022545472, 401498.540025887, 402817.872126163, 
    404031.355449687, 405119.064633836, 406063.139523877, 406848.078436217, 
    407460.992695616, 407891.818266879, 408133.481006037, 408182.012817595, 
    408036.616810547, 407699.68038331, 407176.736022705, 406476.370460674, 
    405610.083680384, 404592.100086817, 403439.134942437, 402170.119903037, 
    400805.892160482, 399368.852296588, 397882.596466191, 396371.528948936, 
    396371.528948936), .Dim = c(51L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, 
        c("X_rotated", "Y_rotated"))), bbox = structure(c(238115.783982185, 
    384561.045080277, 240120.939367694, 408182.012817595), .Dim = c(2L, 
    2L), .Dimnames = list(c("X_rotated", "Y_rotated"), c("min", 
    "max"))), proj4string = new("CRS", projargs = "+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.1561605555556 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs")))
```

The dataframe with geographical points is as follows:

```
> dput(cbind(adjust_total_stations$X,adjust_total_stations$Y))

structure(c(129853.213357373, 203682.475442269, 2763.2251461125, 
83666.495800621, 159437.426857475, 160060.554915487, 44663.021345273, 
346577.124224787, 326519.04325017, 344673.903599519, 283275.350611723, 
258232.454941985, 251345.593064552, 339213.135671216, 264969.831639921, 
254120.040975795, 323556.587783146, 214659.546145064, 313117.139769511, 
296376.023401034, 205286.999205306, 235830.781422624, 203891.678034808, 
279628.734070735, 266670.443375652, 285373.754300692, 314436.960214308, 
285432.138190941, 294787.421035628, 228293.459090064, 244682.891482491, 
271520.002036511, 317074.970230107, 285280.68089835, 291405.353582627, 
228696.876282164, 306109.637019016, 275003.385158434, 277514.824673875, 
333134.631311625, 284856.481595046, 302170.364824746, 242075.113728822, 
261496.259236603, 246260.176087144, 294785.166738704, 199925.606908265, 
114235.451470764, 114280.345961269, 123874.837501061, 127371.415126819, 
152258.446163919, 101756.715050525, 140802.697563979, 154784.241643151, 
164026.007345779, 179364.066322246, 188849.761738603, 188318.790812958, 
209047.270587744, 214285.150917458, 235129.986510439, 235179.970080805, 
242062.156554381, 272803.150500692, 257631.778530425, 30475.202390311, 
35593.2177688951, 48393.4463326564, 50689.9091334886, 68103.5303276381, 
72044.8590736535, 82345.1735737047, 90380.9209645991, 123307.232881161, 
123715.725509022, 138384.096674224, 154290.918489938, 177127.990069963, 
181267.254479522, 181363.983663669, 211231.342699152, 359175.519917971, 
280285.186375429, 375408.951549105, 371117.745425505, 325080.109898742, 
295023.536048384, 333476.05699758, 553398.618528535, 502723.805722857, 
484647.013152539, 305959.024680789, 432670.822034079, 368325.499858705, 
431522.671459174, 380631.571377824, 303381.786753131, 567099.781849722, 
389815.080456533, 463205.937244183, 531823.687436082, 339302.527631784, 
279641.641119984, 419405.888971759, 320927.769212729, 334518.84140709, 
505111.370837517, 528427.852959961, 527087.909030178, 319090.752391603, 
298767.924267731, 316284.10193135, 637712.426503894, 335996.553472669, 
356170.658091926, 479738.170832674, 367246.123906066, 620645.793221048, 
360993.57004493, 601763.764048506, 631684.720581318, 553646.66915427, 
421892.543064125, 624399.296451532, 455920.987331294, 391910.963395046, 
402792.227144616, 312239.934647189, 549163.125211842, 481284.207138301, 
583924.976961403, 517467.64850425, 600630.434960004, 502322.80497157, 
456881.771524581, 545653.648132082, 496701.961412502, 581994.125411096, 
524072.138117317, 452077.690368563, 603272.335287218, 494491.523943221, 
529842.877962494, 571581.223288614, 454174.13350868, 580257.816757263, 
477285.686814565, 385185.512969457, 378050.990332112, 360739.898778152, 
394188.148051304, 445602.269012438, 388562.950364056, 384955.423944628, 
441925.910852381, 442498.502534531, 397548.014018176, 430076.049349805, 
384657.310483297, 407846.337140399, 356578.544033963, 324093.563434182, 
390198.611620222), .Dim = c(82L, 2L))
```

I've tried rewriting both to sf objects and to use `st_contains` but this just yields an empty list, which I know is incorrect. Could somebody provide me with the quickest way to solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi @Luuk S. Your `dput(Severity_matrix[1:2,17])` gives `points`, not `polygons`

Comment: Ah yes I see, however, I did try to transform it to an sf object using ```st_as_sf``` and it did not work. Could you perhaps tell me how to transform my data so that I can use ```st_contains```  or another equivalent function?

Comment: I guess, the problem is that your `Spatialpoints` are in a list. So you need to use `lapply` to convert them into `sf` objects. You could try something like this : `lapply(pts, st_as_sf)` with `pts` as your list of `Spatialpoints`. The result will be a list of `sf` objects. That said, these are points, not polygons.

Comment: It worked, thank you! The main problem was indeed that I tried directly applying the functions to a whole list instead of using ```lapply``` and applying it to its elements.

Comment: O.K. Glad that I could help. Cheers.

Comment: Looks like you've posted two versions of the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70451292/find-which-data-observations-are-located-within-spatial-object-in-r

Comment: Oh that is weird. This one does not contain the edits, so it must have gone wrong during editing.